# PullAsync and PushAsync with integer Autonumber Identity as well as GUID ID using Azure Mobile Server/Client SDK

Tags: azure, xamarin, azure-mobile-services, azure-sdk

I have an existing table having "CustomerID" as the primary key integer autonumber. 
I then added the GUID based"ID" as per the rules of Azure SDK for Offline sync to work.
I am able to PULL the data using PULLASYNC. I can also PUSH the data via PUSHASYNC. The PUSH gets an error if I include the "CustomerID" field in the model. I need this CustomerID field in the DB offline as well. But then I cannot PUSH using CustomerId=0 or CUstomerId=null.

Now, could you help that somehow I can PUSH the model without CustomerID(either set as 0) and then on PULL, get the CustomerID autonumber from the SQL server?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Very interesting problem. Are you not able to use a different primary key instead, as that would seem to solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

In the table controller in your Node or C# server code, you can remove the CustomerId property when you receive an update (PUT) or insert (POST) for this table, before executing the database operation. Then in the response body, include the CustomerId property with the value assigned by the database.